# MapApply Operator Form

Tags: functions, functional-style

I have a list of matrix sequences (list of matrices) that I want to multiply, something like

```
mylist = {{a,b,c}, {a,b} , ...}
MapApply[Dot,list] = {a.b.c, a.b, ...}
Dot@@@mylist = {a.b.c, a.b, ...}
```

These work fine. However, I had wanted to use the operator form `MapApply[Dot]` (e.g. for postfix notation). However, both `MapApply[Dot][mylist]` and `mylist // MapApply[Dot]` fail to evaluate. This is confusing [because according to the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html), "`MapApply[Dot,mylist]` is equivalent to `MapApply[Dot][mylist]`".

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please name the symbols starting with a lower-case character. Built-in names start with an uppercase letter. `C`, `D` , `E` and other symbols have predefined meanings in Mathematica. How about `L // Dot @@@ # &` ?

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  `MapApply` was introduced in version 13.1, and the operator form does not work in earlier versions.

Comment: The operator form works as expected with v13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)

Comment: Ah thanks, I am running version 13.0. This seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapApply was introduced in version 13.1, and in my testing all forms of it work,

```
MapApply[f, list]
f @@@ list
MapApply[f][list]
```

Interestingly the first usage also works in versions 10 through 13.0 because of the `"MapApplyCompatibility"` paclet, which does not contain the definition for the operator form (third usage above).